# orient-db: does the 2.2 Spatial Module provide a new way to achieve NEAR functionality?

Tags: orientdb, spatial

i'm looking to do queries similar to those described in [the pre-2.2 spatial-index documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html#near-operator):

```
SELECT *, $distance FROM Class WHERE [<lat-field>,<long-field>,$spatial] NEAR [lat,lon,{"maxDistance": distance}]
```

(i would also like to sort by `$distance` which i haven't tried yet, but hope works)

[this documentation for the 2.2 spatial-module](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Module.html) says that it is a "replacement" for the spatial-index feature mentioned above.

if spatial-module is a replacement for spatial-index, is there a new way to achieve the spatial-index `NEAR` functionality with spatial-module, or is the older spatial-index `NEAR` syntax still the way to go?

if the answer is "yes", use the older syntax, does this mean that i would need both discrete lat/lon fields and an embedded `OPoint` to use both feature sets?

if the answer is "no", use newer syntax for `NEAR` functionality, can someone provide an example?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new SpatialFunction to do that with the new Module.It wasn't documented. It's called STDWithin.

I've updated the docs here
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/Spatial-Index.md#st_dwithin

It will be in the official docs in a couple of hours

Comment: thanks @wolf4ood, on a related note, is it possible to just store lat/long as discrete float fields on an entity and still gain the benefit of this new module using something like `ST_GeomFromText(format("POINT(%d,%d)", lat, lon))` to create a point on the fly? or do we literally need the embedded OPoint type document to gain the benefits of indexes...?

Comment: @tony_k is not possible. The new module rely on the OPoint